# Why is my windows shell extension being invoked when I run an executable as administrator?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-10, shell-extensions

I'm working on a project that integrates with the Windows 10 file explorer to allow users to open selected files in our program. The shell extension I made works fine for the most part, but the problem I'm having is that my extension's IShellExtInit::Initialize(...) and IContextMenu::InvokeCommand(...) are being invoked when I right click an executable in my start menu results and click "Run as administrator". As far as I can tell, the only point in my code where I can confirm that my extension should actually be running when it is invoked is in [DllGetClassObject(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) by checking that rclsid and my extension's GUID are equal.

For the basic setup of the shell extension, I followed [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih3NuiUACnI&list=PLJUZSom8IAAL7QTeKv9icTsf5fxf_uWMs). The example extension in the videos only appeared for text files, but I changed mine to work on all file types.

Does anyone have any idea where this problem could be coming from? Here are the relevant parts of my code: https://gist.github.com/caevrobe/2865b5f472d668352a7a91fb5c66953a

Comment: Your `InvokeCommand` must [check the `lpVerb`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120516-00/?p=7613) and perform its action only if the verb matches the context menu's verb. (Make sure you define a verb for your command and return it from `GetCommandString`. That allows the system to move your command to a background thread.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks so much for the clarification! I read your devblog posts a lot while working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/60f9d8b3-8e2d-4751-9e33-fb0735e1b700/my-context-menu-shell-extension-breaks-run-as-administrator?forum=windowssecurity). My fix was to return E_INVALIDARG if pici->lpVerb != NULL in my IContextMenu::InvokeCommand(...). When invoking "Run as administrator" pici->lpVerb was "runas". When using my extension through the context menu normally, it was null.

```
HRESULT MyContextMenuHandler::InvokeCommand(LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici) {
    if (pici->lpVerb != NULL)
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    // rest of your code...
}
```

I'll leave the question up in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-invokecommand) for `InvokeCommand()` says: "*If the verb, specified either by a canonical verb name or the command ID is not recognized by the context menu handler, it must return a failure (E_FAIL) so that the verb can be passed on to other context menu handlers that might implement it.*"